# Remove lines by line number in python

Tags: python

I have a normal text file (.txt) and want to make it into a string for easy processing. The file has 80 lines, but I don't want to include lines 1-4 and 74-80. Right now I have the full file including those lines.

```
with open("textfile.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()
    clean_text = ""
    for line in text:
        clean_text += line.replace("\n", " ")
print(clean_text)
```

This code only replaces the newline characters by a space, but I also want to exclude the lines I previously stated.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Did you mean 74-80 rather than 84-80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as file:
    text = ''.join([line.replace("\n", " ") for line in file.readlines()[5:74]])
```

Of course assuming its 74-80 instead of 84-80.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a counter to the program and check if that iteration isn't in the list. An example could be like this:

```py
with open("textfile.txt") as file:
    ignore_lines = [1,2,3,4,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]
    text = file.readlines()
    clean_text = ""
    inter = 1
    for line in text:
        if inter not in ignore_lines:
            clean_text += line.replace("\n", " ")
        inter += 1
print(clean_text)
```

Comment: You should use `enumerate` instead of a manual counter. Also, the name `inter` doesn't make sense to me, I recommend to call this `linenum` or simply `i`. Another suggestion is to use a set instead of a list to improve the time complexity.